# cURL to PHP equivalent

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to correctly convert a cURL command to PHP, but I can't seem to find the correct commands.  I can run this command with cURL but I need to run this through TROPO, and they only have a few script options.

So I am trying in PHP.

```
curl https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/310029000547353138383138/setNum \ -d access_token=e650d0dec0476de7d64b23110fed31dcb3cbxxxx \ -d args=2085555555
```

My try, what am I missing?

```
<?php
    function submitValue() {
      $ch = curl_init("https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/310029000547353138383138/setNum");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'access_token=e650d0dec0476de7d64b23110fed31dcb3cbxxxx&"args=2085555555"');                                                                       
      );

      $output = curl_exec($ch);

      if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != '200') {
        return null;
      }
      return $output;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Is `*>` a typo or is it present in your original code? (Should be `?>`)

Comment: @Matt funny thing is, `*` and `?` are far away from each-other in keyboard. So how it can be a **typo**

Comment: @nmnsud :D I mean, of course, is the error in the original code or was it introduced when transcribing it to Stack Overflow?

Comment: @nmnsud also, it isn't true of all keyboard layouts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Japanese.svg

Comment: @Matt Ahh! its completely different from my keyboard. :)

Comment: It was a typo, I had a comment at the bottom and replaced the / but forgot the *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use cURL command below:

```
curl --data "access_token=e650d0dec0476de7d64b23110fed31dcb3cbxxxx&args=2085555555" https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/310029000547353138383138/setNum
```

Got this answer from https://superuser.com/a/149335

## UPDATED:

Here I have provided PHP code:

```
$data = json_decode(array(
      "access_token" => "e650d0dec0476de7d64b23110fed31dcb3cbxxxx",
      "args" => "2085555555"
));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/310029000547353138383138/setNum');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: That works as well. But I don't see the PHP solution for it.

Comment: That worked, but in my reading I thought CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS was like adding parameters to the URL and that -d put the info in the body.